# Complex type with C linkage in C++11

Tags: c++, c, c++11, complex-numbers, complextype

I need to include the header of a C library into my C++11 code. Now, the header provides routines and data structures that involve plenty of `double complex` all over the place. E.g.,

```
#include <complex.h>
//..
typedef struct parameters
{
    // ...
    double complex Vud;
} parameters;
// ...
double complex polylog(int n, int m, double x);
```

I bring this file into my C++11 source wrapped in `extern "C" { #include "include.h" }` (that's the actual filename, believe it or not). And g++ (tried 4.7.3 and 4.8.2) and clang (3.3) go nuts if I have -std=c++11 added.

The millions of lines of g++ errors include plenty of:

```
include/g++-v4/cmath:98:3: error: template with C linkage
```

And clang gives:

```
cmath:84:3: error: declaration conflicts with target of using declaration already in scope
  abs(double __x)
  ^
/usr/include/stdlib.h:773:12: note: target of using declaration
extern int abs (int __x) __THROW __attribute__ ((__const__)) __wur;
           ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3/include/g++-v4/cstdlib:245:14: note: using declaration
  using std::abs;
             ^
```

I am not sure how to get around this. What is the correct way to do this? Clearly these must be inter-operable, but I do not know the trick.

Comment: Sounds like a `using namespace std;` or `using std::complex` at global namespace level, possibly in a header included first. Try out just including the C header in a **minimal program**.

Comment: ↑ Oh, I tested it and the compiler is really somehow confusing the macro `complex` (which expands to `_Complex`) with some template called `complex`, presumably the `std::complex` template. Weird. Anyway, I see no way to consume the C syntax in C++ other then **preprocessing** the header, possibly manually.

Comment: @Alf, here is hello-world that just includes the header in "C" linkage (with some clang error output): http://ideone.com/tkZb4d

Comment: @Alf, in the gnu/gcc headers, `<complex.h>` -> `<ccomplex>` -> `<complex>`, and the first thing `<complex>` does is `#undef complex`

Comment: I'm sorry, apparently I need more coffee. But the upshot is that a header that should work in both C and C++ can't directly use the C syntax like `double complex` or even `double _Complex`. What it can do is use a `typedef` name that is defined differently for C and C++; I would just use conditional inclusion of a language specific header. Happily the C++11 `std::complex` is designed to be memory layout compatible with C complex numbers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In 100% standard C++, you just plain cannot include standard headers in an `extern "C"` block. You would need to modify your `include.h` header to be C++-friendly, by first including its required headers outside of `extern "C"`, and declaring its own names inside an `extern "C"` block.

> **17.6.2.2 Headers [using.headers]**
>
> [...]
>
> 3 A translation unit shall include a header only outside of any external declaration or definition, and shall include the header lexically before the first reference in that translation unit to any of the entities declared in that header.

Doing

```
extern "C" {
#include <complex.h>
}
```

is invalid, because the header is then included inside of a declaration. This applies even if it's another header that only indirectly includes `<complex.h>`.

What may work on common implementations, as a workaround if modifying `include.h` is impractical, is to first manually include all the headers that `include.h` would include itself. Assuming those headers use the appropriate guards to make a second inclusion a no-op, the fact that `include.h` includes them will then not cause any errors.

Comment: I did not know this, so I appreciate the answer. I agree that including the <> headers preemptively makes sense. Still, I am left with trying to get C++11 to understand what `double complex` is within C linkage. Any ideas there? If I were able to modify the header, would the goal be to replace `double complex` with `complex<double>`?

Comment: @sujeet Both C's `double complex` and C++'s `complex<double>` are required to be stored as two consecutive `double` objects, where the first specifies the real part, and the second specifies the imaginary part. So, for practical purposes, yes, you should be able to use `complex<double>`. This does involve modifying the header, as Cheers and hth. - Alf commented on your question. You will not be able to define `complex` as a macro in such a way that `double complex` expands to anything you could use.

Comment: I inserted a flag to hide the `#include <complex.h>` from my C++11 code, and swapped it out for `#define complex _Complex` around the C linkage. Apparently `_Complex` is not portable, but it at least lets me move on, for now.