# building a solution of a large project seems to give an error in math.cpp

Tags: c++, macos, declaration, cmath

I am working on a large project that consists of many separate .cpp and .h files that have been compiled in the past on a Windows machine. Now I have this project on a MacBook Pro. I have spent some time on adding all the files to the project and building a solution.

I managed to delete all errors except the following. In the file cmath.cpp there seems to be an issue with the function abs. The issue arises in the following piece of code:

```
// abs

#if !defined(_AIX)
inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
float
abs(float __x) _NOEXCEPT {return fabsf(__x);}

inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
double
abs(double __x) _NOEXCEPT {return fabs(__x);}

inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
long double
abs(long double __x) _NOEXCEPT {return fabsl(__x);}
#endif // !defined(_AIX)

#ifndef __sun__
```

Specifically, the line

```
abs(double __x) _NOEXCEPT {return fabs(__x);}
```

returns the following error message while building the solution:

"Declaration conflicts with target of using declaration in scope"

How can this be? The math.cpp functions have been tested by their creators in the past. So what is going on here?

Comment: Probably related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22115996/3959454

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. Why do you think this is related?

Comment: Because the same error is described in that question. There is a standard function `abs` and your declaration seems to conflict with it.

Comment: I see. But does this mean that I have defined the function abs somewhere in my project as well? As I cannot change the math.cpp file...

Comment: It's declared in `<stdlib.h>`